# Telegram API message error, how avoid words missing

Tags: python, api, markdown, telegram, message

I try to send a telegram message from python through the api, the message is a preformed text like the following:

````py
message = (f"```test: Hello World \n"
           f"time : {datetime.datetime.now()}```")
````

but I only receive the following in the telegram bot:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the word `test:` is missing

From now, thank you for you help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a newline(`\n`) after the markdown syntax:

````
message = (f"```\ntest: Hello World \n"
           f"time : {datetime.datetime.now()}```")
````

Answer (score 0):

After some time reading on the internet, I found this other solution:

````
message = (f"```python\n"
           f"test : Hello World \n"
           f"time : {datetime.datetime.now()}"
           f"```")
````